# Flexbox wrapping lines, can you lay out 3x3 grid with center sized to content

Tags: css, flexbox

Playing around with flexbox I'm not sure I fully get how wrapping works. Suppose I have the following html (without fake `.row` elements, it's easy with those)

```
.flex-container
   .spacer
   .spacer
   .content
   .spacer
   .spacer
```

Is it possible to create a fullsize 3x3 grid where the spacer elements take up all room around the `.content` container (which is size to content and centered horizonally/vertically)

[image: Like this]

Comment: Yes you can, it just depends on how you go about doing it. Have you read [Solved by Flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/grids/)? That might have exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @MattSmith I've seen that in the past but not sure how it applies here. There's no mention of wrapping on that page at all and I specifically do not want to create `.row` elements (this isn't for practical reasons but more me experimenting with the limits flexbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you've solved this by now, but since there are no answers or updates...

As you noted, the issue is partly wrapping.  But wrapping can be *mostly* solved for this pretty easily, simply by setting the top and bottom elements to `flex-basis: 100%`.

The other major issue is that any given flex container primarily represents either the horizontal or the vertical layout, not both. `align-contents: stretch` will make all 3 rows fill space vertically, but I'm not sure it's going to do *quite* what you want.

Given this markup:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="spacer">
    Automatically full width, take up all height between top of center block and container.
  </div>
  <div class="spacer">
    Take up all room available to left of center block.
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Centered and sized to content.
  </div>
  <div class="spacer">
    Take up all room available to right of center block.
  </div>
  <div class="spacer">
    Automatically full width, take up all height below bottom of center block and container.
  </div>
</div>
```

These instructions for flexbox are very close:

```
html, body, {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    height: 100%;
}

.spacer:first-child, 
.spacer:last-child {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

.spacer:nth-child(2),
.spacer:nth-child(4) {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.content {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

The most obvious issues are several:

- The only reason the top and bottom rows fill left over space is their `stretch`, but this will apportion all three rows relatively evenly to take up any leftover space.  Meaning if there is a lot, the top, bottom, and middle will all get some extra vertical stretch.
- The only reason we there are three rows is that the layout can `wrap`, but because it can wrap if the content is so wide that any contents of the left and right spacers can't fit next to it, the spacers and content will also wrap.

Which is not to say you can't account for those by using other properties, but I'm restricting this to what can be done specifically with flexbox.  See these styles here http://codepen.io/morewry/pen/WbqbgN/.  If you play with the size of of `img.arbitrary-content` you will see the limitations for the way most content and most layouts.

The next permutation would be to use two flexboxes, one column and one row.  This is much closer to what I think would be the expectation of behind the drawing.

Given this markup (inserting one row wrapper for the middle):

```
<div class="flex-column">
  <div class="outer-spacer">
    Automatically full width, take up all height between top of center block and container.
  </div>
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="inner-spacer">
        Take up all room available to left of center block.
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Centered and sized to content.
    </div>
    <div class="inner-spacer">
        Take up all room available to right of center block.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer-spacer">
    Automatically full width, take up all height below bottom of center block and container.
  </div>
</div>
```

These are the instructions for flexbox:

```
html, body, {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.flex-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.outer-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.inner-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.content {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

See these styles at http://codepen.io/morewry/pen/wBLBNV.  This one seems safer for real use, if you play around with the size of `img.arbitrary-content`.